# How to convert array to collection in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, collections

What I am trying to do here is convert an array to Collection.
How to do this properly?

Here is my array:

```
PersonList[] personlist = restTemplate.getForObject(url, PersonList[].class);
```

What I doing there is, I get JSON value and consume with restTemplate, then I put it in PersonList array object, but I want to return the value as Collection. Example:

This is very wrong code that I am trying to present:

```
Collection<PersonList> personlist2 = personlist
```

It can't bind the array to collection, cause it's different data type.
Can I convert it?

Comment: Try `Arrays.asList(personList)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this:

```
List<PersonList> list = Arrays.asList(personlist);
```

(Is this `PersonList` itself a list? If not, then why is the class named `PersonList` instead of `Person`?).

Note that the list returned by [`Arrays.asList(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) is backed by the array. That means that if you change an element in the list, you'll see the change in the array and vice versa.

Also, you won't be able to add anything to the list; if you call `add` on the list returned by `Arrays.asList(...)`, you'll get an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

If you don't want this, you can make a copy of the list like this:

```
List<PersonList> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(personlist));
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to use [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-_):

```
Collection<PersonList> personlist2 = Arrays.asList(personlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 PersonList[] personlist = restTemplate.getForObject(url, PersonList[].class);
 ArrayList<PersonList> personlist2 = Arrays.asList(personlist)
```